# Difference between MVC1 and MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

1. What is the difference between MVC1 and MVC2 ?
2. Is everything in MVC1 also in MVC2?   I am asking this question because there is a debate in my place of work.  We can find resources and ebooks on MVC1, but not on MVC2.  Should we use MVC1 in our portal?.
3. Is AJAX functionality implemented the same in Web Forms for MVC2 as MVC1? Are there limitations in MVC2 vs. MVC1?  (Can everything that can be done with AJAX in Web Forms MVC1 be done in MVC2?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) [See this Doc](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=157072)

2) Yes.

3) Yes.  MVC is a much better fit for AJAX or any client side scripting in my opinion.

Comment: ok so whatever ajax functionality we can achieve in web forms ,it can be done it mvc?

Comment: is this the right way here as I have done to get more from the question or I should start a new question.What are comments here for? Adding comments bring the question to the top or not?

Comment: Yes, you can do anything ajax in MWC that you could do in webforms (although you will have to modify your code probably).  You can add comments like this or update your question with an "EDIT:" section.  MVC2 is now final, yes.