# what are some key differences between mvc1 and mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

what are some key differences between mvc1 and mvc2.
I have to adopt any one so i am unable to decide that is mvc2 have some really good features that mvc1 is missing.

Comment: Duplicate? [difference between mvc1 and mvc2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719586/difference-between-mvc1-and-mvc2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project framework choices are usually constrained by environment, developer skills and knowledge etc.  If you have no constraints and the freedom of choice then why would you want to use an older outdated version?  Just use MVC 2.

But if you just want to know what was updated in MVC 2 then take a look at [Scott Guthrie's series of posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

- New strongly typed helpers
- Editor and display templates

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can say after switching to MVC2 there is one big advantage: Speed. Our webfront is much faster in rendering. Also additional helper-classes and better security are just some more improvements made.

Finally it's just a newer version - so why stay at an old one? Also there hadn't been any issues when updating to MVC2...